# Flutter Provider Package and Google Signin using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I am trying to create a simple signin with google using provider package

but getting a list of huge errors can someone help me out with this please i am new in flutter

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Register Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Register is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:358:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:295:30)
#2      _RegisterState.build. (package:instagramclone/screens/register.dart:21:22)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
#14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
#15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
#16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
TapGestureRecognizer#6a4e1
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
    **my code which has only a button** 
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Register> createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);

            //context.watch<AppProvider>().signInWithGoogle;
          },
          child: Text("Login with Google"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**packages i am using **

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1
firebase_storage: ^10.2.0
provider: ^6.0.1
firebase_core: ^1.10.2
image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
video_player: ^2.2.7
google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
firebase_auth: ^3.3.0

please help me what am i doing wrong

Comment: where is the parent `AppProvider` provider widget??

Comment: in my runApp  "void main() async {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      //  ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppProvider())

      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppProvider()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));

  // const MyApp());
}"